# wpf ListView как выровнить Items на ровне со столбцами

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Я переопределил стиль у ListView, но не пойму как мне контент Items выровнить чтобы он был на ровне со столбцами. Я переопределил  `Template` чтобы избавить от градиента при выделение или нажатии на `Iteam`
Код

```
 <ListView Name="phonesList" ItemsSource="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=phones}" >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Модель" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Title}"></GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Company}" Width="100">Компания</GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Price}">Цена</GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
            <ListView.Resources>
                <col:ArrayList x:Key="phones">
                    <local:Phone Title="iPhone 6S" Company="Apple" Price="54990" />
                    <local:Phone Title="Lumia 950" Company="Microsoft" Price="39990" />
                    <local:Phone Title="Nexus 5X" Company="Google" Price="29990" />
                    <local:Phone Title = "Galaxy Edge" Company = "Samsung" Price = "45670" />
                </col:ArrayList>
            </ListView.Resources>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                <Border BorderThickness="2" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" Content="{Binding Title}"/>
                                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" Content="{Binding Company}" />
                                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="2" Margin="5" Content="{Binding Price}" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
```

Cейчас такой вид у ListView
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Прикладываю код, для переопределения шаблонов стилей ListView
Цвет при наведение на скриншоте красный
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<Window x:Class="ViewBoxDesign.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ViewBoxDesign"
        xmlns:col="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <!--Control colors.-->
        <Color x:Key="WindowColor">#FFE8EDF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ContentAreaColorLight">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ContentAreaColorDark">#FF7381F9</Color>

        <Color x:Key="DisabledControlLightColor">#FFE8EDF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="DisabledControlDarkColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="DisabledForegroundColor">#FF888888</Color>

        <Color x:Key="SelectedBackgroundColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="SelectedUnfocusedColor">#FFDDDDDD</Color>

        <Color x:Key="ControlLightColor">White</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ControlMediumColor">#FF7381F9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ControlDarkColor">#FF211AA9</Color>

        <Color x:Key="ControlMouseOverColor">#FF3843C4</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ControlPressedColor">#FF211AA9</Color>


        <Color x:Key="GlyphColor">#FF444444</Color>
        <Color x:Key="GlyphMouseOver">sc#1, 0.004391443, 0.002428215, 0.242281124</Color>

        <!--Border colors-->
        <Color x:Key="BorderLightColor">#FFCCCCCC</Color>
        <Color x:Key="BorderMediumColor">#FF888888</Color>
        <Color x:Key="BorderDarkColor">#FF444444</Color>

        <Color x:Key="PressedBorderLightColor">#FF888888</Color>
        <Color x:Key="PressedBorderDarkColor">#FF444444</Color>

        <Color x:Key="DisabledBorderLightColor">#FFAAAAAA</Color>
        <Color x:Key="DisabledBorderDarkColor">#FF888888</Color>

        <Color x:Key="DefaultBorderBrushDarkColor">Black</Color>

        <!--Control-specific resources.-->
        <Color x:Key="HeaderTopColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="DatagridCurrentCellBorderColor">Black</Color>
        <Color x:Key="SliderTrackDarkColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>

        <Color x:Key="NavButtonFrameColor">#FF3843C4</Color>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MenuPopupBrush"
                     EndPoint="0.5,1"
                     StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}"
                Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}"
                Offset="0.5" />
            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}"
                Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBarIndicatorAnimatedFill"
                     StartPoint="0,0"
                     EndPoint="1,0">
            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Color="#000000FF"
                    Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#600000FF"
                    Offset="0.4" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#600000FF"
                    Offset="0.6" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#000000FF"
                    Offset="1" />
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        
        
        
        

        <Style x:Key="GridViewColumnHeaderGripper"
       TargetType="Thumb">
            <Setter Property="Width"
          Value="18" />
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                           EndPoint="0,1">
                        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                            <GradientStopCollection>
                                <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderLightColor}"
                          Offset="0.0" />
                                <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderDarkColor}"
                          Offset="1.0" />
                            </GradientStopCollection>
                        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                        <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                Background="Transparent">
                            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                     Width="1"
                     Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
                           StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="Black"
                      Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="White"
                      Offset="1" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}"
       TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
          Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
          Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
          Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                        <Grid>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                    (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderBorder">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                         Value="{StaticResource ControlMouseOverColor}" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border x:Name="HeaderBorder"
                  BorderThickness="0,1,0,1"
                  Padding="2,0,2,0">
                                <Border.BorderBrush>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                                   EndPoint="0,1">
                                        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                            <GradientStopCollection>
                                                <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderLightColor}"
                                  Offset="0.0" />
                                                <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderDarkColor}"
                                  Offset="1.0" />
                                            </GradientStopCollection>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>

                                </Border.BorderBrush>
                                <Border.Background>

                                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                                   EndPoint="0,1">
                                        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                            <GradientStopCollection>
                                                <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}"
                                  Offset="0.0" />
                                                <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}"
                                  Offset="1.0" />
                                            </GradientStopCollection>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>

                                </Border.Background>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContent"
                              Margin="0,0,0,1"
                              RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                              SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Thumb x:Name="PART_HeaderGripper"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                 Margin="0,0,-9,0"
                 Style="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderGripper}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Role"
             Value="Floating">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity"
              Value="0.7" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                                <Canvas Name="PART_FloatingHeaderCanvas">
                                    <Rectangle Fill="#60000000"
                         Width="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                         Height="{TemplateBinding ActualHeight}" />
                                </Canvas>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Role"
             Value="Padding">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                                <Border Name="HeaderBorder"
                    BorderThickness="0,1,0,1">
                                    <Border.Background>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" />
                                    </Border.Background>
                                    <Border.BorderBrush>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                                     EndPoint="0,1">
                                            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                <GradientStopCollection>
                                                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderLightColor}"
                                    Offset="0.0" />
                                                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderDarkColor}"
                                    Offset="1.0" />
                                                </GradientStopCollection>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Border.BorderBrush>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="{x:Type ListView}"
       TargetType="ListView">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
          Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
          Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility"
          Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility"
          Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll"
          Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
          Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListView">
                        <Border Name="Border"
                BorderThickness="1">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource ControlLightColor}" />
                            </Border.Background>
                            <Border.BorderBrush>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource BorderMediumColor}" />
                            </Border.BorderBrush>
                            <ScrollViewer Style="{DynamicResource
                        {x:Static GridView.GridViewScrollViewerStyleKey}}">
                                <ItemsPresenter />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsGrouping"
                   Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll"
                    Value="false" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                   Value="false">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border"
                    Property="Background">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource DisabledBorderLightColor}" />
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="{x:Type ListViewItem}"
       TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
          Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
          Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Border x:Name="Border"
                Padding="2"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                Background="Transparent">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                    <!--Цвет при наведение мыши-->
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                    (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                         Value="Red" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                                    <!--Цвет при выборе Iteam-->
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                    (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                         Value="{StaticResource SelectedBackgroundColor}" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                    (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                         Value="{StaticResource SelectedUnfocusedColor}" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <GridViewRowPresenter VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Margin="231,48,0,0">
        <Grid Margin="30">
        </Grid>
        <ListView  Name="phonesList" ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DataContext="w">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding ID}" />
                        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
                        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Value}" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Модель" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ID}"></GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" Width="100">Компания</GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value}">Цена</GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Вы не ответили на свой вопрос, а лишь дали портянку кода, который да, может и решает поставленную задачу, но не объясняет почему, как, и в чем была изначально проблема. Ну а проблема у вас была в том, что вы топорно впихнули непойми зачем в стиль сетку с привязанными конкретными данными, когда вместо сетки должен быть `GridViewRowPresenter`. На будущее, не ленитесь смотреть документацию, ведь там [все есть](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/listview-styles-and-templates), ну и не ленитесь пользоваться студией, которая в 2 клика за вас сгенерирует дефолтный стиль.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ссылку что вы предоставили, я от туда и взял код, и изменил его немного под себя. 
```которая в 2 клика за вас сгенерирует дефолтный стиль``` у меня нет правки копии шаблона для ListView. ```GridViewRowPresenter``` Попробую это, спасибо за наводку